# How to compare dynamic strings using C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a following string format

Cover:

> Category 1(1 is dynamic) - Type - Google(Google is dynamic), some dynamic strings

I want to confirm that whether Category, Type and some dynamic strings following are present under Cover header using C#

What could be the best approach to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Have you checked regular expressions? They are the best solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

if u wana IgnoreCase

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(myString, Regex.Escape("Category"), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) && .....){}
```

else use

```
if( myString.Contains("Category") &&.....) { }
```

if have a list of words u can use a loop let me know i will edit ans according to that

Comment: Category has total 8(Category 1, Category 2,Category 3,Category 4,Category 5,Category 6,Category 7,Category 8)  and 5 types are(Type-Google, Type-Yahoo, Type-Facebook,Type-Twitter, Type-Instagram) and after comma it has some random strings(here just wanted to know that whether it is empty or not after comma

Comment: @vinoth please edit ur question with the appropriate string and tell me where is this space appearing and also give a bit more information so I give more appropriate ans

Comment: Using includes may cause false positives.

Comment: @Alexis includes ? i'm not able to follow can please explain thanks

Comment: @Avinash as OP stated, there may be some random text after type, so if "Category 1" or another type name appears there you could get false positives. It's usually a bad practice to use contains unless there is no better way of doing it. In this case, the best solution is to use regex,

Comment: @Alexis `I want to confirm that whether Category, Type and some dynamic strings following are present under Cover header using C#` he just wanted to check these words exists so Contains will work fine